# How to show a recursive sequence is monotone by induction

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, induction

the sequence we consider is $(b_n)_{n_{\ge0}}$, which is defined by:

$b_0 = -1$ , $b_1 = \alpha$, $b_{n+1} = \sqrt{\alpha + b_n} \; \; \forall \: n \ge 1$, with $\alpha \ge 2 \ \ \land  \alpha \in \Re$

We are supposed to show that $(b_n)_{n}$ is asymptotically monotonely decreasing using induction.

My ansatz so far has been:

$\exists N \in \mathbb{N} | \forall n \ge N \ \ b_{n+1} \le \ \ b_n $

But beyond that, I have no idea on how to include induction to prove this..

Comment: $b_0=-1$ plays no role in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If $b_n<b_{n-1}$, then
$b_{n+1} = \sqrt{\alpha+b_n}<\sqrt{\alpha+b_{n-1}}=b_n$
so we have our induction propagation.

If $\alpha>2$, then $b_2=\sqrt{2\alpha}<\sqrt{\alpha^2}=\alpha=b_1$
so we have our initial condition for induction. (And for $\alpha=2$ the sequence is constant at $2$).